# Back button confirm doesn't work in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, back-button

In one page of my AngularJS app I want to display a confirm if the user click on the browser back button :

[image]

So I added a listener on stateChange to detect this behavior, and if the user don't want to go back I cancel it.

Here is my piece of code :

```
angular
    .module('app.platform')
    .run(start);

start.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state'];
function start ($rootScope, $state) {
    // Save navigation
    $rootScope.previousState = null;

    // State change listener
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', stateChangeStartListener);


    function stateChangeStartListener(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        // app.platform.quiz is the state that I want to display a confirm if the user
        // uses the back button
        // Then I record and check the previous state reached to know that the user uses the back button
        if(fromState.name === 'app.platform.quiz'
            && $rootScope.previousState
            && $rootScope.previousState  === toState.name) {
            if(confirm("Do you really want ot leave the quiz ?")) {
                $rootScope.previousState = fromState.name;
                $state.go(toState, toParams);
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        } else {
            $rootScope.previousState = fromState.name;
        }
    }
}
```

When the user hits **OK** button it works well, but when he hits **Cancel** I got a strange behaviour. He stays on the page, but if he hits the back button again nothing happen (no confirm, no go back), and if he hits back button again he go back 2 states before.

It sounds like my `event.preventDefault()` mess with the history.

I'm not very familiar with the HTML5 History API, but maybe it can solve my problem.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong ? Or why I got this behaviour (and how to correct it).

### EDIT :

After some reading (from comments), I know what is the problem, and how to solve it (only in theory).

**I need to catch the back button click before it change the URL, but I think it's not possible**.

Comment: I've got that problem myself and tried a lot of ways, finally solved by this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1780

Comment: You can read this nice post https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/cancelling-route-navigation-in-angularjs

Comment: Thanks for that I'll read it

Comment: I read these and try to apply it, but it still doesn't work. But I have a better comprehension of my problem. I need to know that the user click on back button before the browser url change. But I think it's not possible